# paperjs: drag two items in one go without changing their relative position

Tags: paperjs

Which functionality of paperjs should I use so that two items can be dragged in one go without changing their relative position i.e. both the items should move irrespective of which item I am dragging. I have tried doing it with group but it doesn't work. I don't want to make it a compound path either because I want to join/combine two or more items dynamically for dragging purpose.

[sketch link](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.12.3/S/tZTBa8IwFMb/lUcvrVCkRmTg2MldBBmDDXZQDzF52miaSPrUDfF/X2Jd1U10O6yXNt976ff1/Uq2keEFRt3oZYEk8iiNhJVhveYOhHJCYwsewOAGnjnlzd5eSrYjA/4SaAhdF4bQyrIUOhmM06riuFSrsuv1gzBVWvestr47dijjkdk17kdmZIKRVubcZuCFL5Ops8UlC7K12jqRS3J2gV9WE73C+KzypiTlvtI5Rlg6O0dBTS5IrXHAP9A1uZS9XGmZHIZwDEv4TnVYqwy9eiGpV0mV6C5rhC375uZ8VZKaKsFJWeO3xtXg4rqhnk4oTjQXi2NNWP9gKFT6RpHiGpa2VOFVcR2qSsl+g4p9n9jfWbFbrH54VLD2Mvt3WOwcFrsCq0p0AovdgsWuwGKnsB4dn81QXoAVWtvXQnWylB0jtW9Fal+J1D6N9GSh4OR3wiZHyv29D9LHPPw+kHjaDbAVZEgCj0YKE0s5KMKihDK3Ky2hsGsEZYC4kVgEK39wTBzyxTJ8QBl1h+PdJw==)

In the given sketch, one end of line coincides with the center of circle. Now whether I drag Circle or Line, both the items should move without changing their relative position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Groups](http://paperjs.org/reference/group/) are designed for this purpose, [here is a working example](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.12.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).